# Thymeleaf nested list/ArrayList - get total size of all elements

Tags: thymeleaf

List has 2 elements [0], [1].

Element in list - [0] has five elements in nested ArrayList 
    [0] [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]

[1] has 4 elements
    [0], [1], [2], [3] , [4]

How can I get the total **length/size** in Thymeleaf, i.e 9? I need to use it outside of any loops if possible to hold a temporary value.

Which brings me to the next question, how can I hold local custom variables in Thymeleaf using just the .size and not iterating through the data structure? I am ready to write a loop to get this .size if needed but I want to store it in a local variable that I can possibly reuse later in another loop!

Example:

```
<div th:each="test : ${testList}">
    <div th:each="testItem : ${test.subArrayList}">
        <div th:each="testItemSub : ${testItem}">
            <span> Get total size of "${testItemSub.name}" and store in a variable</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With newer versions of Thymeleaf, you may be able to just use ${#lists.size(list)} for the size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a local variable via the `th:with` attribute per http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables .  However, I've found no way to update that local variable within the element once it's set.  In other words, unlike JSP, variables cannot be created and manipulated within the view/template.

The easiest way to solve your particular use case would be:

1. Set an model object containing a method that will take in the `ArrayList` as its parameter and return the count.  Obviously, you can implement any logic you need in Java code.

   - Similarly, a Spring bean instead of a model object can be used.  Used by the syntax: `${@myBean.doSomething()}`
2. Use the `#ids` expression utility object that comes with Thymeleaf.  It can be used as a counter within the template if you use an id of `''`.  However, this will only work if there is only one such counter within the entire template.  Ref:  http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#ids

Example usage of `#ids` based on the original question:

```
<div th:each="test : ${testList}">
    <div th:each="testItem : ${test.subArrayList}">                                 
            <div th:each="testItemSub : ${testItem}">
                    <span> Get total size of "${testItemSub.name}" and store in a variable</span>
                    <!--/*/ <th:block th:text="${#ids.seq('')}"></th:block> /*/-->
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p>There are a total of <span th:text="${#ids.prev('')}">123</span> elements.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I used approach 1.

Comment: If you want multiple integer counters on the page, you could do:

`${#strings.replace(#ids.seq('imageThumbs'),'imageThumbs','')}`